# Changing the colour of a single section in KOMA-Script

Tags: sectioning, color, koma-script

I would like to change the colour of a single section, while its color remains unchanged in the table of contents.

I've tried following code but it seems like that it does not work with the KOMA-Script:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

{\color{red} \section{Name of the section}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work, because the font element `disposition` is used for the headings, too. Default setting for `disposition` is `\normalcolor\sffamily\bfseries` and the `\normalcolor` overwrites your color setting.

You could use the hooks in the headings which are provided by the KOMA-Script classes:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*\nextheadingcolor[1]{%
  \AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/begingroup}{\setheadingcolor{#1}}%
}
\newcommand*{\setheadingcolor}[2]{\addtokomafont{#2}{\color{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\nextheadingcolor{red}
\section{Name of the section}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{Foo}

\nextheadingcolor{green!50!black}
\subsection{Colored subsection}

\subsection{Bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use `\addtokomafont` inside a group:

```
\begingroup
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{red}}
\section{Capybara}
\endgroup
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
    
\begingroup
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{red}}
\section{Capybara}
\endgroup

\section{title}

\end{document}
```

[image]